# for each column, calculate the difference between it and the max of the others

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(2,3,2), c=c(4,5,1))
#  a b c
#1 1 2 4
#2 2 3 5
#3 3 2 1
```

For each column, I would like to calculate the difference between that and the max of the other columns:

```
# Desired result:
#    a   b   c
#1  -3  -2   2
#2  -3  -2   2
#3   1  -1  -2
```

For example, for the (1,1) entry, it's 1 because for the first row, `a = 1`, and `max(b,c) = 4`, so `1 - 4 = -3`.

Note that I don't necessarily know the number of columns in the dataframe up front, so there could be arbitrarily many columns.

Comment: The max(b,c) = 5. Your desired result isn't correct as displayed, although the intention is clear.

Answer (score 6):

This should work on any number of columns:

```
sapply(1:ncol(x), function (i) {
  x[,i] - do.call(pmax, x[,-i])
})
```

Comment: yikes. the `do.call` did it, and i'm not quite sure why calling `pmax` directly doesn't work. :|

Comment: `pmax` expects the vectors to be passed in as individual parameters, e.g. `pmax(x[,2], x[,3], x[,4])`.  With `do.call`, we can separate a list (including a data frame) into its components and pass them into a function as if we specified each individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `dplyr` solution with a bit of RC indexing, you can use `transmute` to generate a new data frame, or `mutate` to add to your existing dataframe.

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(2,3,2), c=c(4,5,1))
x %>% transmute(a = a-max(x[,-1]),
                b = b-max(x[,-2]),
                c = c-max(x[,-3]))
```